# Trying to install innodb memcached plugin MySQL5.6.17 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, memcached, innodb

I am trying to setup innodb memcached plugin. I am running MySQL 5.6.17 server on ubutnu 14.04 box. I have upgraded the MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6, but didn't get libmemcached.so with default installation.

So, I compiled MySQL from source manually and then copied libmemcached.so and innodb_engine.so to /usr/lib/mysql/plugin directory. But while installing the plugin I am getting error

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.6.17-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@plugin_dir;
+------------------------+
| @@plugin_dir           |
+------------------------+
| /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> install plugin daemon_memcached soname 'libmemcached.so';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'libmemcached.so' (errno: 0 API version for DAEMON plugin is too different)
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu repository doesn't have MySQL memcached plugin library.

I suggest to use MySQL APT Repository.

Guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I realized it works with fresh installation by compiling source code. But, if you compile the source and copy the so file to default installation it doesn't work.